# Lags with nonconsecutive index

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with a missing index, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(2000:2004, 2006), value = c(0:4,6) ^ 2)
#   year value
# 1 2000     0
# 2 2001     1
# 3 2002     4
# 4 2003     9
# 5 2004    16
# 6 2006    36
```

I would like to compute the lagged value for each year. If I use the lag function,

```
library(dplyr)
wrong <- mutate(df, prev = lag(value, order_by = year))
#   year value prev
# 1 2000     0   NA
# 2 2001     1    0
# 3 2002     4    1
# 4 2003     9    4
# 5 2004    16    9
# 6 2006    36   16
```

it gives a lagged value for 2006 despite not having data on 2005. **Can I get the previous year's value with the lag function?**

Currently, I know I can do the following, but it's inefficient and messy:

```
right <- df %>% group_by(year) %>% 
    mutate(prev = ifelse(sum(df$year == year) == 1, df$value[df$year == year-1], NA))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups: year [6]
#     year value  prev
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2000  0    NA   
# 2  2001  1.00  0   
# 3  2002  4.00  1.00
# 4  2003  9.00  4.00
# 5  2004 16.0   9.00
# 6  2006 36.0  NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one simple approach:

```
mutate(df, prev = value[match(year - 1, year)])
#   year value prev
# 1 2000     0   NA
# 2 2001     1    0
# 3 2002     4    1
# 4 2003     9    4
# 5 2004    16    9
# 6 2006    36   NA
```